# Openiddict using EF Core and tables not being generated automatically like in EF6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, openid, openiddict

We are porting our application over to EF Core and also updating our openiddict code to use EF Core as well. We have found that when a new database is setup, if the tables are missing, they are not created like it would do in EF6. Is this correct?

This is our code at the moment, which runs but when the user tries to login the tables are not there.

```
var applicationDbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
await applicationDbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
```

In EF6 we had the following

```
using (var applicationDbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IApplicationDbContext>())
    applicationDbContext.Database.Initialize(false);
```

This would generate the tables for us if they were missing and add an entry to the `__MigrationHistory` table.

The rest of the code is very simple

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    // Configure the Entity Framework Core to use Microsoft SQL Server.
    options.UseSqlServer(appSettings.Data.DefaultConnection.ConnectionString);

    // debug
    if (appSettings.Debug)
    {
        options.EnableDetailedErrors();
    }

    // Register the entity sets needed by OpenIddict.
    options.UseOpenIddict();
});
```

```
// OpenIddict
services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
            .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
    })
```

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Are we supposed to go about it a different way?

Comment: From the documentation "Use migrations or recreate the database to add the OpenIddict entities." https://documentation.openiddict.com/integrations/entity-framework-core.html

Answer (score 0):

you might want to inherit from IdentityDbContext which exist in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore

something like this

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
```

or

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

etc

if you have a custom IdentityUser, IdentityRole, and/or key then add your migration

or you might want to add all of that manually to your DbContext as DbSets if you don't want to inherit from IdentityDbContext
read the documentation for more info
https://documentation.openiddict.com/integrations/entity-framework-core.html